# Handle Multiple Form tag in asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My page contains a user control and inherits a master page.  Both have a button.  I have put it in a form tag.  I am just trying to do an event bubbling from master page as well as user control. Now it doesn't load because of multiple form tags error. How to do it?

**Masterpage :**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="SampleSite.master.cs" Inherits="EventBubbling.SampleSite" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="MasterPageButton" />
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**User control :**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="SampleUserControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="EventBubbling.Controls.SampleUserControl" EnableViewState="false" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUC" runat="server" OnClick="btnUC_Click" Text="UserControlButton" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**User control.cs page :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace EventBubbling.Controls
{
    public partial class SampleUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler buttonClick;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnUC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonClick(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Page :**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" MasterPageFile="~/SampleSite.Master"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="EventBubbling._Default" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/SampleUserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="SampleUserControl" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc:SampleUserControl ID="UC1" runat="server" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace EventBubbling
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Button btn = new Button();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UC1.buttonClick += new EventHandler(UC1_buttonClick);
            btn = this.Master.FindControl("Button1") as Button;
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

        }

        void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("EventBubbling from MasterPage");
        }

        void UC1_buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("EventBubbling from User control");
        }

    }
}
```

My goal is to learn event bubbling but I get some basic error with this code I posted.

Answer (score 3):

your user control should not have a < form> tag, this is taken care of by the MasterPage all pages / controls are then rendered inside this master control < form> tag.

If you want to have your user control with its own form you will have to change to a different MasterPage and to be honest I am not sure how that would even work.

Comment: don't put the user control in a form tag. the master page is enough as squirrel stated

Comment: nice one, i was not aware of other controls take form tag from master page

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX, MasterPages are what they say. Other pages are just "Content". So they dont need do declare < html> tags or < header> etc as this is all provided by the Master. If you try to add another < form> tag you will be placing a form inside a form

Comment: Thanks @SecretSquirrel ..but when i am placing a control(button) and try to catch its event from main page ..i am getting an error .."Control 'ctl00_head_UC1_btnUC' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."

Comment: @SecretSquirrel what you shared is perfect but here i have two button ..1 in Masterpage  another in usercontrol ...i want to handle both from my main page ...its better if i get an example

Comment: @RahulChowdhury handle both from the "main" page? (I assume MasterPage) my first thought would be why...

Answer (score 2):

Keep Id of form different every where you are using form tag.

every where its `<form id="form1" runat="server">`.

Make it as `Id=1 , Id=2` ,etc.

In master page keep form `Id=1` , in user control page make it as 2 and in main `aspx` make it as 3.

Or Remove form tag from usercontrol page.

Comment: Still getting same error..."A page can have only one server-side Form tag."..can you help me with sample code

Comment: do one thing, remove form tag from master page

Comment: I did it it is getting error . saying butoon of master page must be in a form tag runat=server..

Answer (score 1):

Since you have placed controls in master page, you need to keep the `<form>` tag thereon.

The error message: `A page can have only one server-side Form tag.` should actually be taken as: `A page can have only one visible server-side Form tag.`

*if you want you can have more than one  form tags.
Read here one Great tricks of Asp.net: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2005/10/19/482778.aspx . Definitely not of much practical use.*

Else, You need to correct the Markup of your userControl. Remove tags like: head, html, form.
Your final markup of UserControl will be:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="SampleUserControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="EventBubbling.Controls.SampleUserControl" EnableViewState="false" %>
<div>
<asp:Button ID="btnUC" runat="server" OnClick="btnUC_Click" Text="UserControlButton" />
</div>
```

I hope you get the idea what all needs to be removed.

All such pages or usercontrols that are going to be a part of this master page must not contain any `<form>` tag.

Comment: The specific problem is the server-side form tag.  You can have multiple, non-server-side forms on a single page.

Comment: Still I am getting error man .."Control 'ctl00_head_UC1_btnUC' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."..Thanks anytime

Comment: @Rahul: the error must be clear by now. This is because you have included your userControl in the ContentPlaceHolder with ID=head. Check markup of your main page. and again next check that this ContentPlaceHolder with ID=head  is outside the <form> tag ( in markup of your Master page ).